# Dynamic Controls in WPF - Adding a variable number of controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to dynamically add controls into another control (I know this is a bit vague...). My program is in C# 4.0, and WPF.  Basically, I'm trying to create a datagrid but as opposed to having normal type 'cells' (ie text, hyperlink etc), I need each cell to hold a number of items.  I figured that this wasn't possible in the datagrid, so I'm trying to do the following:  Using a stack panel, add a variable number of wrap panels. Each wrap panel will contain 7 grids, where each grid will hold the data I want (I'll likely use some user control in place of the grid I think...)

An example of the code I have so far...

```
            <StackPanel Height="559" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,11,0,0" Name="tyStackPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="783">
                <WrapPanel Height="100">
                    <Grid Width="100" Height="100">

                    </Grid>
                </WrapPanel>
                <WrapPanel Height="100">

                </WrapPanel>
            </StackPanel>
```

Is there a way to create a variable number of Wrap Panels though? (ie like you would have a variable number of rows in a datagrid)

Any help and suggestions is much appreciated!

P.S. Figure I should explain what I'm trying to achieve a bit better.  I have a collection of items, each with 5 properties that I want displayed together.  These items are grouped by Name (like a row in a data column) and a column header (which is not one of the 5 properties). I want to group the collection by (Name, ColumnHeader) pairs, and then in each "cell" display those 5 properties.  In the way I'm trying to set it up above, there would be a WrapPanel per 'Name' and a Cell/Grid contained in  it for each ColumnHeader.

Comment: You really need to read up on ItemsControl and data templates.

Comment: Yea, I'm definitely not an expert on this stuff... at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF supports this very well with the `ItemsControl` and its various derived controls, one of which is the `DataGrid`, which actually *does* support the scenario you're looking for.

Basically, when you use an `ItemsControl`, `DataGrid` or one of these item controls, you bind the `ItemsSource` to whatever property holds your data items, and define the `DataTemplate`s for each item, which can be any arbitrarily-complex block of XAML. For `DataGrid`, you can swap a normal column for a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, which can, again, be as complex as you want.

Check out the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) for, well, an overview.

Comment: Hi Avner, thanks for your reply.  Where would I find an ItemsControl, as I don't see it in the toolbox (I'm next to useless with WPF....)

Comment: I've never used the toolbox, I have to admit. I've found that writing the XAML manually is much, much faster. Especially with Visual Studio 2010 being so hopelessly slow rending the XAML.